# how i can get last 10 days records with mysql

Tags: mysql

I want retrieve all data of the last 10 days records, but when I add a 'where' it doesn't work like expected.

my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `vip` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cancel_at_period_end` datetime NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime default NULL,
 `answer` varchar(5) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=499 ;
```

i have used query like:

```
SELECT days.day, count(users_vip.id) count
FROM (SELECT curdate() as day 
                          union select curdate() - interval 1 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 2 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 3 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 4 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 5 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 6 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 7 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 8 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 9 day) days
LEFT JOIN users_vip on days.day = CONVERT(users_vip.creation_date, date)
WHERE users_vip.current_period_end_date >= NOW()
GROUP BY days.day
```

output is :

```
date          count
2018-08-15    1
```

The result I want should be like this:

```
date          count
2018-08-08    0
2018-08-09    0
2018-08-10    0
2018-08-11    0
2018-08-12    0
2018-08-13    0
2018-08-14    0
2018-08-15    1
2018-08-16    0
2018-08-17    0
```

UPDATE:

```
SELECT days.day, count(users_vip.id) count
FROM (SELECT curdate() as day 
                          union select curdate() - interval 1 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 2 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 3 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 4 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 5 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 6 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 7 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 8 day
                          union select curdate() - interval 9 day) days
LEFT JOIN users_vip on days.day = CONVERT(users_vip.creation_date, date) AND users_vip.current_period_end_date >= NOW()
GROUP BY days.day
```

Comment: "I'm not sure that's the problem. I think the OP should be left joining the entire calendar table to a subquery which finds the date counts" Hard to say without example data by the way @TimBiegeleisen.. I saw a common SQL error using WHERE (without column IS NULL) in combination with LEFT JOIN and made a comment about it..

Comment: @RaymondNijland You're right, and Spencer's answer takes note of that...but in my version it is not an issue.

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: The constant selection of curdate() is going to evaluate too often and those function calls will slow things down.  do  a select curdate() by itself and then do the date math.  The other thing you can do is query another table with "limit 10" and assign dates to it thus eliminating the unions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should left join your calendar table to a subquery which aggregates the counts by day:

```
SELECT
    days.day AS date,
    COALESCE(t.cnt, 0) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT CURDATE() AS day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 day UNION
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 day
) days
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE(creation_date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM users_vip
    WHERE current_period_end_date >= NOW()
    GROUP BY DATE(creation_date)
) t
    ON days.day = t.date;
```

Comment: Your solution was great but instead of mark 0 on an empty date, it shows NULL.

Comment: @MappyLord That should not be the case.  Reload your page, I used `COALESCE` in the select clause to handle this.  Other than this, my query should be working for you.

Comment: My bad, I tried and it's working fine but I prefer the answer of @Raymond Nijland, no need to change my query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can change `WHERE` to `AND`, to relocate the predicate from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

I'd also avoid the function wrapper around `creation_date`, to allow for an index to be used. I'd re-write that matching condition.

I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT days.day
     , COUNT(users_vip.id)     AS count
  FROM ( SELECT CURDATE() AS day 
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -1 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -2 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -3 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -4 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -5 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -6 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -7 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -8 DAY
         UNION ALL SELECT CURATE() + INTERVAL -9 DAY
       ) days
  LEFT
  JOIN users_vip
    ON users_vip.creation_date            >= days.day 
   AND users_vip.creation_date            <  days.day + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND users_vip.current_period_end_date  >= NOW() 
 GROUP
    BY days.day
```

Comment: "I'd also avoid the function wrapper around creation_date, to allow for an index to be used" About time MySQL should support functional or expression indexes like PostgreSQL does. Well you could simulate this feature by using MySQL's generated column and index that.